# How do I make my code asynchronous ? (Google Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension which collects data from two servers and sends it to another service. I don't understand how to make it asynchronous. The requests seem to work fine.

I searched Google for some explanations but just found some basic tutorials with timeouts. Also, the Product-Server accepts the Ajax request, the Deal-Server doesn't (CORS Error). So I used XMLHttpRequest.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var createButton = document.getElementById("createButton");
    createButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        getProducts();
        getDeals();
    }, false)


    function getProducts() {
        var list = [];
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
            var Url = parseDealIdToUrl(tab.url)
                $.get(Url, function (data, status) {
                    const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
                    const productArray = jsonData.data
                    productArray.forEach(product => {
                        productList.push(new Product(product.id, product.deal_id, product.product_id, product.name, product.item_price, product.quantity, product.duration, product.discount_percentage, product.currency, product.sum, product.sum_formatted))
                    });

                })
        });
    }

    function getDeals(maxPages = 1, currentPage = 1, akquises = []) {
        var akquiseList = akquises;

        if (currentPage <= maxPages) {
            var Url = dealUrl + currentPage
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", Url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token token=")
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    const akquiseArray = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    akquiseArray.forEach(akquise => {
                        akquiseList.push(new Akquise(akquise.name, akquise.id))
                    });
                    getDeals(handlePagination(xhr.getResponseHeader("Link")), currentPage + 1, akquiseList)
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
}, false)
```

I want to call both functions and wait till both Lists are filled, then send the Data to the Service. Any idea would help me!

Comment: just a note..  *"Also the Product-Server accepts the Ajax request, the Deal-Server doesn't (CORS Error). So I used XMLHttpRequest."* `$.get` or `$.ajax` IS an `XMLHttpRequest.` moving from one to the other isn't necessarily what fixed it.

Comment: The requests are already asynchronous (by default) so I guess what you want is to promisify getProducts and getDeals and do Promise.all() + then(). There should be tons of tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "make it asynchronous." As wOxxOm said, XMLHttpRequest is an asynchronous method. Do you mean you're not sure how to combine the results of multiple asynchronous operations? For the sake of this answer I'll assume that's the case.

### Basic Asynchronicity

In order to break down how asynchronous functions work, let's look at a simplified example of your code. Below we have a main function that calls 2 different asynchronous functions. When you run this block you'll get a `DONE` message logged to the console, `Async 1 complete` logged after 1 second, and `Async 2 complete` logged 1 more second later.

```js
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

(function main() {
  doAsync1();
  doAsync2();
  console.log('DONE');
})()


function doAsync1() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Async 1 complete');
  }, 1000);
}

function doAsync2() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Async 2 complete');
  }, 2000)
}
```

The reason `DONE` is logged before the other statements is because `doAsync1` and `doAsync2` are asynchronous – it take a couple seconds for them to complete their work. When you call `doAsync1()` in `main`, the JS engine will step into the `doAsync1` function and start executing lines. The first line is a `setTimeout` call. This function takes its first argument and schedules it for execution 1000 milliseconds later.

At this point the JS engine has done everything it can in `doAsync1`, so it steps out of that function and calls the next line, `doAsync2`. Again, `doAsync2` schedules its callback for future execution and returns.

Next, the engine will execute the `console.log` line which makes `DONE` appear in the console.

1000 ms later, the callback scheduled by doAsync1 will run execute and log `Async 1 complete` to the console. Another 1000 ms later the callback scheduled by `doAsync2` will log `Async 2 complete`.

### Basic Callbacks

Now let's say `doAsync1` and `doAsync2` generate some data we want to use in `main` once both of complete. In JS, we traditionally use callbacks to get notified when some operation we're interested in completes.

```js
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function doAsync1(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Async 1 started');

    const data = "Async 1 payload";
    callback(data);
  }, 1000);
}

function doAsync2(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Async 2 started');

    const data = "Async 2 payload";
    callback(data);
  }, 2000);
}

(function main() {
  const response = {};
  doAsync1(handleAsync1);
  doAsync2(handleAsync2);

  function handleAsync1(data) {
    response.async1 = data;
    handleComplete();
  }
  function handleAsync2(data) {
    response.async2 = data;
    handleComplete();
  }
  function handleComplete() {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty('async1') && response.hasOwnProperty('async2')) {
      console.log('DONE', response);
    }
  }
})();
```

### Promises

While this does the job, it's a bit verbose. Promises are an abstraction of one-time callbacks that makes it easier to chain blocks of work together.

```js
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Promisified version of setTimeout
function timeout(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

function doAsync1(callback) {
  return timeout(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('Async 1 started');
    const data = "Async 1 payload";
    return data;
  });
}

function doAsync2(callback) {
  return timeout(2000).then(() => {
    console.log('Async 2 started');
    const data = "Async 2 payload";
    return data;
  });
}

(function main() {
  // Starts both doAsync1 and doAsync2 at the same time. Once both complete, the
  // promise will resolve with both response values.
  Promise.all([
    doAsync1(),
    doAsync2()
  ]).then(response => {
    console.log('DONE', response[0], response[1]);
  });
})();
```

### Async/Await

With [ES2016](https://2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html) we gained 2 new keywords: `async` and `await`. These keywords are essentially syntactic sugar that make it a little easier to work with promises in JavaScript. For demo purposes, let's take a look at our Promises example converted to async/await.

```js
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function timeout(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

async function doAsync1(callback) {
  await timeout(1000);
  console.log('Async 1 started');
  const data = "Async 1 payload";
  return data;
}

async function doAsync1(callback) {
  await timeout(2000);
  console.log('Async 2 started');
  const data = "Async 2 payload";
  return data;
}

(async function main() {
  const response = await Promise.all([
    doAsync1(),
    doAsync2()
  ]);
  console.log('DONE', response[0], response[1]);
})();
```

For a much deeper dive into async functions, check out [Async functions - making promises friendly](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions) by Jake Archibald.

Comment: Thank you, your examples have helped me a lot. It took me some time but I managed to rewrite my code and now it's all done. I've used `Promise.all` + `then()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code snippet to add async/await functions to chrome extension.
**Usage:** put the following code snippet to the beginning of both your content script and background script.

```js
/**
 * Usage:
 * let cookies = await asyncfy(chrome.cookies.getAll)({ url })
 * let tabs = await asyncfy(chrome.tabs.query)({active: true, currentWindow: true})
 *
 * @param fn  A function that takes one or more parameters, and the last parameter is a callback which has one or more parameter. The simplest one is chrome.management.getSelf
 * @returns {function(...[*]): Promise<any>}  Return one value if the results array has only one element, else return the whole results array
 */
let asyncfy = fn => (...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(...args, (...results) => {
      let { lastError } = chrome.runtime
      if (typeof lastError !== 'undefined') reject(lastError);
      else results.length == 1 ? resolve(results[0]) : resolve(results);
    });
  });
}


let isObject = function(obj) {
  var type = typeof obj;
  return type === 'function' || type === 'object' && !!obj;
};


// provide async method to all methods which have one callback.
let handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    let value = target[prop]
    let type = typeof value
    if(type !== 'undefined') { // including null, false
      if( type === 'function') return value.bind(target); // correct the this for the functions, since we've substituted the original object to the proxy object
      return value;
    }

    if(prop.endsWith('Async')){
      let key = prop.replace(/Async$/, '')

      let method=target[key]
      let asyncMethod = asyncfy(method.bind(target));

      return asyncMethod;
    }
  }
}

// proxy every leaf object
let asyncfyObj = handler => obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
  .filter(prop => isObject(obj[prop]))
  .forEach(prop => obj[prop] = new Proxy(obj[prop], handler))

// intercept the getters of all object in chrome member
asyncfyObj(handler)(chrome)
asyncfyObj(handler)(chrome.storage)


// console.log(`active tab: ${JSON.stringify(await getActiveTabAsync())}`)
let getActiveTabAsync = async () => {
  let tabs = await chrome.tabs.queryAsync({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  return (tabs && tabs.length > 0) ? tabs[0] : null;
}

// chrome.storage.local.set({ foo: 'bar' });
// console.log(`foo: ${await getLocalStorageAsync('foo')}`)
let getLocalStorageAsync = async key => ( await chrome.storage.local.getAsync([key]) ) [key];
```

**Testing:** put the following snippet in your background script and make sure related permissions have been added to the manifest.json.

```js
(async () => {
console.log(cookies: ${JSON.stringify(await asyncfy(chrome.cookies.getAll)({ url: 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/' }))})

console.log(active tab: ${JSON.stringify(await getActiveTabAsync())})

chrome.storage.local.set({ 'foo': 'bar'});
console.log(storage: ${await getLocalStorageAsync('foo')})

console.log(extension install type: ${( await chrome.management.getSelfAsync() )['installType']})
} )()
```

[my gist](https://gist.github.com/BigSully/4468a58848df07736757a73d722d81f5)